# Expression in Tender is the Night

Tags: sentence, literature

In *Tender is the Night* by Fitzgerald, what does the following sentence mean? Could someone break it down into pieces and explain?

> Just as the personal qualities of extraordinary people can make themselves plain in an unaccustomed change of expression, so the intensely calculated perfection of Villa Diana trans- pired all at once through such minute failures as the chance apparition of a maid in the background or the perversity of a cork.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to **isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs**.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first place, Fitzgerald said exactly what he wanted to say and any attempt to abridge it borders on travesty, because it is not the actual text.

That caveat stated, I'll give it a go. In simpler words (I hope), and in a different order, it means

> Sometimes we see that an uncharacteristic change of expression can reveal personal qualities in extraordinary people. That is how the clockwork perfection of Villa Diana was revealed all at once in such tiny errors as the appearance, by chance, of a maid in the background or the failure of a cook to act in harmony with the place.

And I would sum up the takeaway as

> Villa Diana revealed its true nature through tiny cracks in its otherwise perfect façade.

Comment: Can you explain *transpire* here?  It seems backwards.  //  Also, I think the original does say CORK, not COOK.

Comment: @aparente001 Transpire is used with the meaning of _be revealed_ with reference to a secret as defined by the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transpire). What Fitzgerald is saying is that the Villa Diana was so well run that the no one realised the amount of effort and organisation that went into producing that effect until something very minor went wrong like a cork being difficult to remove from a bottle. This is like a swan appearing to glide serenely on a river while it is paddling furiously below the surface.

Comment: @aparente001 My  print version says *cork*.

Comment: As BenBold says, the perfection that Fitzgerald says one sees through by chance at stray moments is the perfection of supposed effortlessness, as though the villa were so nearly perfect that it maintained itself in unblemished condition without human intervention and effort.

Comment: @SvenYargs: Yes, but Fitzgerald being Fitzgerald the emphasis would be on the worm and not the apple.

Comment: @BoldBen - Would you please put this in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Transpire is used with the meaning of be revealed with reference to a secret as defined by the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transpire)

What Fitzgerald is saying is that the Villa Diana was so well run that the no one realised the amount of effort and organisation that went into producing that effect until something very minor went wrong such as a cork being difficult to remove from a bottle. This is like a swan appearing to glide serenely on a river while it is paddling furiously below the surface.

Answer (score -1):

> The small errors in otherwise perfect things will ruin it.

That is probably what is said. Personal qualities of extraordinary people are used as an example to explain the phenomena in the context of Villa Diana.

EDIT: The answer of Robusto explains how that phenomena could be applied. The imperfect thing may has more imperfections hidden.